.NET installation in vs code (C# dev kit) problem
I am trying to code a console app in C# in vs code because visual studio's size is so large and my wifi is slow. I installed the extension C# Dev Kit and when I tried to create a projecr with ctrl+shift+p an output popped up that it is installing .NET 7 I kept it 2 hours and it didn't install I checked the task manager and vs code was not using internet connection.
please help.
I am using windows 8.1/ vs code 1.79.2
I tried installing .NET separately from Microsoft and I have putted the path in the .NET install tool vs code extension. and when I restarted it showed this output and nothing happened: Using configured .NET path: C:\Program Files\dotnet

According to https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/core/install/windows, .NET 6 is the last version that supports Windows 8.1.
